# What is a good name for this parameter?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

What would be a good name for a parameter that *controls* what a function does? Currently I have been using `ref`, and have thought about using `status` instead but neither of those make sense.

**Example:**

```
function getItem(ref, key) {
    if (ref == 1) {
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    else if (ref == 2) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I vote for Claire, it's such a pretty name. This is however opinion-based

Comment: `action` is a common one..

Answer (score 0):

i vote for "switch". it's not pretty as Claire, but has a point too...

Comment: `switch`is also a reserved keyword, that can't be used for variables, so it's probably the worst suggestion you could come up with. Don't know if it was intentional or not ?

Comment: i guess it's just late here and i should not think about mixing semantics with recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's two different types of storages then why not name it `type` or `storageType`?